# How to run Presto discovery service standalone?

Tags: presto, trino

How to run Presto Discovery Service standalone so it's neither a coordinator nor a worker? What are the requirements of a HTTP endpoint to become a discovery service for a Presto cluster?

I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/presto-users/c/AetYYMvfsiA) on presto-users mailing list where David Phillips wrote:

> If you want to run discovery as a standalone service, separate from
> Presto, that is an option. We used to publish instructions for doing
> this, but got rid of them years ago, as running discovery inside the
> coordinator worked fine (even on large clusters with hundreds of
> machines).

Does this still hold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can run a standalone discovery service. The cases for this are rare and in general I recommend just running it on the coordinator.

On your discovery node:

1. Download the [discovery service tar.gz](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/airlift/discovery/discovery-server/) with the version that is compatible with your Presto nodes. (e.g. presto version 347 is compatible with [discovery service 1.29](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/347/pom.xml#L754)) and untar it to a directory.
2. Similar to a Presto Server setup, create an `/etc` directory under the service root and configure the [node.properties](https://trino.io/docs/347/installation/deployment.html#node-properties) and [jvm.config](https://trino.io/docs/347/installation/deployment.html#jvm-config).
3. Add the config.properties, which for discovery service is as simple as this.

```
    http-server.http.port=8081
```

4. Update these lines in your coordinator/worker config.properties.

```
    discovery-server.enabled=false
    discovery.uri=http://discovery.example.com:8081
```

5. Restart your services. (Discovery service is started the same way the [presto services are started](https://trino.io/docs/347/installation/deployment.html#running-presto) using `bin/launcher`)
6. Once all the servers and workers come up, you should be able to check `curl -XGET http://discovery.example.com:8081/v1/service` and should expect to see some output that contains:

```
{
  "environment": "production",
  "services": [
    {
      "id": "d2b7141e-d83f-4d23-be86-285ff2a9f53d",
      "nodeId": "57ac8bd3-c55e-4170-b363-80d10023ece8",
      "type": "presto",
      "pool": "general",
      "location": "/57ac8bd3-c55e-4170-b363-80d10023ece8",
      "properties": {
        "node_version": "347",
        "coordinator": "true",
        "http": "http://coord.example.com:8080",
        "http-external": "http://coord.example.com:8080",
        "connectorIds": "system"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "f0abafae-052a-4758-95c6-d19355043bc6",
      "nodeId": "57ac8bd3-c55e-4170-b363-80d10023ece8",
      "type": "presto-coordinator",
      "pool": "general",
      "location": "/57ac8bd3-c55e-4170-b363-80d10023ece8",
      "properties": {
        "http": "http://coord.example.com:8080",
        "http-external": "http://coord.example.com:8080"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1f5096de-189e-4e25-bac3-adc079981d86",
      "nodeId": "8d7e820f-dd01-4227-ad6e-f74b97202647",
      "type": "presto",
      "pool": "general",
      "location": "/8d7e820f-dd01-4227-ad6e-f74b97202647",
      "properties": {
        "node_version": "347",
        "coordinator": "false",
        "http": "http://worker1.example.com:8080",
        "http-external": "http://worker1.example.com:8080",
        "connectorIds": "system"
      }
    },
    ....

  ]
}
```

Comment: Ah, so this discovery service is more like airlift-way of discovering services which Presto is one of many, huh?!

Comment: I’m not sure I exactly follow but Presto internally uses airlift for discovery and other internal node communication via REST. So there’s not an airlift  way vs a Presto way. This is just a method to run the discovery service on its own rather than on the coordinator node. Does that make sense?

Comment: Airlift predates Presto. We built it and open-sourced it when we worked at Proofpoint. It was the toolkit we used to build all our distributed services. When we started working on Presto at Facebook, we leveraged many parts of Airlift, including Discovery.